# Location permission check and authorization

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, location, mapkit

I want my program to display the users location on the map.  It was working at first then randomly stopped so i added the code below to try to fix it but I'm having problems. Thanks in advance!

```
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
        {

            let status: CLAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
            if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined
            {
                locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            }
            } else {

                print("locationServices disenabled")
            }
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
            mapView.delegate = self
            centerMapOnLocation(initialLocation)
            addBoundry()
    }
```

Comment: What problems do You have?

Comment: We need more information regarding issues you are facing. Also I notice there are 2 calls to 'startUpdatingLocation' method of 'locationManager'.

Comment: Did you set the required field in info.plist?

Comment: This is the error I am getting: "Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You required to call,

```
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

as well

```
 locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

to use location smoothly in foreground also!!!

and you should not need two instance to call `startupdatinglocation`. keep one. you should use instance or global variable instead of local to get location throughout the scope.

**Update :**

You have to set two keys in `info.plist` like, `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` with it's usage description.

Comment: Thanks I made those changes but I am still getting the error I commented above

Comment: Note that if you let the description key blank, your app will be rejected by Apple (mine got 08/17)

Comment: You can't leave those plist descriptions blank anymore.

Comment: @KlimczakM : Yeah! We can't leave it blank in latest updates. Updated answer. Thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue, even with `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`set in info.plist. My debugger told me to also set `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription`...so I did it. It worked!

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. I wish apple would stop moving decisions like this around from version to version.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the "WhenInUse" notification you should only add "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description" in your info.plist but if you want the "Always" access your info.plist should look like this info.plist screenshot:

[image]

You don't have to add any request authorization like requestAlwaysAuthorization or requestWhenInUseAuthorization

Answer (score 1):

This is my code:

First import the library:

```
import CoreLocation
```

A little example:

```
        let status: CLAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined || status == CLAuthorizationStatus.denied || status == CLAuthorizationStatus.restricted
        {
            locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
```

And don`t forget to add these permissions in the Info.plist:

[image]