# Why does my app not display the alert to ask to access user's location?

Tags: ios, swift, location

I am developing a navigation app in iOS which uses Location Services but I am having a problem with it. I have a `UITableViewController` object which creates an instance of `LocationManager`, configures it for desired accuracy, distance filter, etc. I have delegates for `didUpdateLocations` and `didChangeAuthorization` but for some reason it crashes under the following conditions. Location Services are turned off, I launch the app and I get an alert to turn on Location Services which I do and then return to the app expecting it to display another alert about asking to access the user's location but it never appears. The app crashes when I selecting a row in my table because the user's current location hasn't been initialised in my `UITableViewController`. `didUpdateLocations` is not being called.

```
//  CountiesTableVC.swift
//  TableViewsApp
//
//  Created by Stephen Learmonth on 10/12/2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 Stephen Learmonth. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class CountiesTableVC: UITableViewController {

    let england : England = England()
    var countiesArray : [String] = ["Northamptonshire",
                                    "Bedfordshire",
                                    "Hertfordshire",
                                    "Staffordshire",
                                    "Essex",
                                    "North Yorkshire",
                                    "Herefordshire",
                                    "Cornwall",
                                    "Dorset",
                                    "Derbyshire",
                                    "Leicestershire",
                                    "Lancashire",
                                    "Cheshire",
                                    "Merseyside",
                                    "Suffolk",
                                    "County Durham",
                                    "Cumbria",
                                    "Gloucestershire",
                                    "Wiltshire",
                                    "Nottinghamshire",
                                    "Devon",
                                    "Somerset",
                                    "Lincolnshire"
                                    ]
    var sortedCounties : [ String ] = []

    var selectedCounty : String? = nil

    var currentCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D! = nil
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        sortedCounties = countiesArray.sorted{ $0 < $1 }

   }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return sortedCounties.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CountyTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CountyTableViewCell

        let county = sortedCounties[indexPath.row]
        let countySites = england.counties[county]
        var siteIsSelectable = false
        if (countySites?.isEmpty)! == true {
            cell.backgroundColor = .gray
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        } else {
            siteIsSelectable = true
            cell.backgroundColor = .blue
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }

        cell.setLabel(cellLabel: sortedCounties[indexPath.row], selectable: siteIsSelectable)

        return cell
    }


    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "toSitesTableVC" {

            let sitesTableVC = segue.destination as? SitesTableVC

            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                selectedCounty = sortedCounties[indexPath.row]
                sitesTableVC?.selectedCounty = selectedCounty
                sitesTableVC?.currentCoordinate = currentCoordinate
            }

        } else {
            return
        }
    }


}

extension CountiesTableVC: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    // get current location if avaialble
    guard let currentLocation = locations.last else { return }

    // get coordinates of current user location
    currentCoordinate = currentLocation.coordinate

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {

            // authorized location status when app is in use; update current location
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            // implement additional logic if needed...
        }

    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: have you added NSLocationUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in plist file

Comment: initialise location manager objet in viewdidload like this locationManager = CLLocationManager()

Comment: Not exactly related but - in `didUpdateLocations` you are taking the very first attempt at a location and running with it. The location manager will send a stream of locations each (hopefully) more accurate than the last. You would normally monitor these returns and stop the manager when some predetermined accuracy has been bettered. The first return could have a huge error/uncertainty or might even contain an error.

Comment: Hi, yes I have already added the info.plist keys.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38727017/2376336

Pretty much it's telling you need to add these keys into into your `info.plist`:

- `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`
- `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`

In the past you could just add them and leave them blank, that's not the case anymore. Make sure to enter proper and concise description for why you need user's location.

Answer (score 0):

if your app requires user's location for "in app use" you need to add

`Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description` in `info.plist`

in case your app requires user's location for "always use" you need to add

`Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description`

`Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description`
 in `info.plist`

Comment: Hi, yes I have added the info.plist key-value pairs to my app.

Answer (score 0):

In `locationManager(manager:didChangeAuthorization)` I needed to change the `if` conditional expression to `status != .authorizedWhenInUse` and make a call to 
`locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` then I get prompted with the second alert to ask to access the user's location. The authorisation level hadn't been changed from `.notDetemined` to `.authorizedWhenInuse` so `locationManager(manger:didUpdateLocations)` didn't have a non-nil value for the user's current location. This nil value was passed to another view controller which was expecting a non-nil value and didn't have one so it crashed.